# How to register my custom MessageConverter to the SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory?

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-cloud, spring-messaging

I have customer converter that implements the MessageConverter interface. However, I dont see a way to register it with the SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory. As a result I get a error when I try to read a message from SQS that is in the source format as it doesnt know how to convert it to the target object.

I looked through the SqsConfiguration class and I see that the simpleMessageListenerContainer bean being defined has a queueMessageHandler set on it. The QueueMessageHandler has resolvers on it, one of which is a CompositeMessageConverter which takes a Collection of MessageConverter types. I am guessing somehow I need to add my custom MessageConverter to this collection. I cant seem to get a handle to how I can do that.

Can someone help help me point to a wayI can register my customer MessageMapper?

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, the only way to really do this is to create your own `QueueMessageHandlerFactory` with whatever resolvers/converters you need.

For example, add this to your `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public QueueMessageHandlerFactory queueMessageHandlerFactory() {
  List<MessageConverter> converters = ...

  CompositeMessageConverter converter = new CompositeMessageConverter(converters);

  QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory = new QueueMessageHandlerFactory();
  factory.setArgumentResolvers(Arrays.asList(new PayloadArgumentResolver(converter));

  return factory;
}
```

`SqsConfiguration` should pick up your `QueueMessageHandlerFactory` bean so it won't create one itself.

Answer (score 0):

The JMS message is converted firstly. After that, MessageListenerContainer transmit the message to the registered listener. So you need register your converter before MessageListenerContainer get it. There is only in  **JmsTemplate** or **JmsMessagingTemplate** call the method ***setMessageConverter*** or ***setJmsMessageConverter*** to configure your converter.